# Change NLS_SORT for a single query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, nls-sort

In a large set of queries, fired in succession through a script, a single query uses REGEXP_LIKE. In it I do not want the regexp ([a-z]) to match diacritics (á, õ, ì). The only way I found to do this, is setting NLS_SORT to BINARY. However, this query should not affect any other query run afterwards.

For this reason, I want to set the variable NLS_SORT only for this query. However, I would rather not resort to PL/SQL. Is there any way to achieve this?

I would prefer this, but according to the docs I found, no such parameter exists:

```
SELECT * FROM dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('ë', '[a-z]', BINARY);
```

I can imagine something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('ë', '[a-z]'); -- match
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = BINARY;
SELECT * FROM dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('ë', '[a-z]'); -- no match
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = DEFAULT; -- not working
ALTER SESSION RESET NLS_SORT;         -- not working
```

- Is there any other way to have the regular expression exclude diacritics than to set NLS_SORT?
- Is there any way to restore the NLS_SORT settings without PL/SQL?

Comment: You could alter session before the query is executed and set the parameter back to what is was after the query execution. Have a look at https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/oracle-case-insensitive-sorts-compares/

Comment: It is DUTCH at the moment, but I would not want to hard code this.

Comment: I can't simulate what you're seeing for some reason - possibly other NLS settings I'm not taking into account. When I can get a match with á, passing either `c` or `i` as the third 'match_param' argument to `regexp_like` stops it matching, which isn't necessarily what I'd expect; might be worth ruling that out?

Comment: Strange behaviour indeed. For me, when I pass `c`, the regex does not match, when I pass `i`, it does. Seems as though the `c` option makes it 'more strict' on my server, to the extend that I get the exact same results as when I adjust NLS_SORT to BINARY. However, as per the docs, it should only affect the case-sensitivity, and apparently it works differently on different systems.

Comment: Apparently, in the Oracle definitions, case-sensitive is a stronger form of accent-sensitive. [Linguistic sorts that use information about base letters, diacritics, and punctuation. This type of sort is called case-insensitive.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm#i1009059). This would make the `c` option for the `match_parameter` the perfect answer for my question!

Comment: @TacoV - you're probably in a better position to turn that into a coherent answer than I am. Glad I accidentally nudged you in the right direction though *8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, thanks to Alex Poole, I reevaluated the `match_paramater` option in REGEXP_LIKE. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501):

> *match_parameter* is a text literal that lets you change the default matching behavior of the function. You can specify one or more of the following values for *match_parameter*:
>
> - ...
> - 'c' specifies case-sensitive matching.
> - ...

Although case-sensitive would not seem to affect whether a matches á or e matches ë, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG0051) is stated that if a sort is case-sensitive, it's also accent-sensitive:

> As of Oracle Database 10g, Oracle Database provides case-insensitive and accent-insensitive options for linguistic sorts. It provides the following types of monolingual and multilingual linguistic sorts:
>
> - Linguistic sorts that use information about base letters, diacritics, punctuation, and case. These are the standard monolingual and multilingual linguistic sorts that are described in "Using Linguistic Sorts".
> - Monolingual sorts that use information about base letters, diacritics, and punctuation, but not case, and multilingual sorts that use information about base letters and diacritics, but not case nor punctuation. This type of sort is called case-insensitive.
> - Monolingual sorts that use information about base letters and punctuation only and multilingual sorts that use information about base letters only. This type of sort is called accent-insensitive. (Accent is another word for diacritic.) Like case-insensitive sorts, **an accent-insensitive sort does not use information about case**.

This states that all accent-insensitive sorts are case-insensitive, and therefore implicitly that a case-sensitive sort must be accent-sensitive.

So, in conclusion:

- Yes, there is a better way to exclude the diacritics: `SELECT * FROM dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('ë', '[a-z]', 'c');`
- No, there is no way to change NLS_SORT for a single query and revert it, without knowing or saving the initial value.

Comment: The behaviour seems to be variable though; [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40437) doesn't match anything; in my (UK, vs. American) environment I do get a match on `REGEXP_LIKE('á', '[a-z]');` but nothing else. So NLS and/or character set still seems to be having an effect. Although I'm seeing that difference in two supposedly identical instances and I have no idea why...

Comment: But, in all cases, *with* the `c` option, diacritics aren't matched, right? It's a one way assertion: `c` forces accent-sensitive behaviour, `i` does not force accent-insensitive, only case-insensitive, behaviour. And omitting the parameter makes the function fall back to NLS settings.

Comment: That *seems* to be a safe interpretation, yes, but on a fairly small sample. From the docs I'd agree, but the behaviour of `i` isn't quite matching, as far as I understand what it's supposed to do. Just being overly cautious probably *8-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you know which carachtes to not match you could implicit outrule them in another regexp:

```
SELECT * FROM dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('ë', '[a-z]') AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE('ë', '[ë]')
```

Comment: Actually, as far as I know and tested, your example does not work. It matches a character a-z, then the start of the string, then an ë. No string matches this regex. You can 'blacklist' characters this way ([^ëéèïíì~#] etc), but since there are so many more 'forbidden' characters then 'allowed' characters, I need to stick to whitelisting.

Comment: Yes, I didn't test this through, edited it and now it's working

Comment: +1 Nice, this would indeed be a single-query solution. Of course, the blacklist would depend somewhat on the original settings, so I'll wait a bit whether a more general answer will come around before accepting.